# PowerShell Exchange online - Download

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Where can I download Exchangeonline?
I am unable to use PowershellGet or NuGet as the proxy won't allow download via PS.

I get the below error.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> find-module exchangeonline
WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 
'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7468 char:21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider -Name $script:N ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider
 
PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria and provider name 'NuGet'. Try 'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable' to 
see if the provider exists on the system.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7474 char:21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider -Name $script:Nu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (NuGet:String) [Import-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.ImportPackageProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct name is ExchangeOnlineManagement

```
Find-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

You can try running it like this to ensure any proxy authentication is passed to the command:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()

[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 

Find-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

Failing this, you can manually download the package from PSGallery - https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangeOnlineManagement/3.0.0 and install it manually - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I am still getting the 'unable to download URI' after running the above commands.

I have also tried installing the .nupkg and receive the below error

PS C:\> Install-Package C:\Users\jackbrooks\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\exchangeonlinemanagement.3.0.0.nupkg
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 
'C:\Users\jackbrooks\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\exchangeonlinemanagement.3.0.0.nupkg'. 
Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+